# Show my own dashboard graph in accounting Odoo10

Tags: graph, odoo-10, odoo

My problem is that I would like to show a `graph` in the accounting `dashboard` of my own Journal. In the `Kanban` it goes completely empty and I would like to show a graph like the one shown in bank. Is this possible from the configuation of the `odoo`? or I have to do it through inheritance or some other way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can set your own journal in dashboard. You follow this step

- Start debug mode
- Go to Account menu -> Journals
- Than go to Advance setting tab -> Enable Show journal on dashboard 

  [image]